# What is being called in this Ruby method?

Tags: ruby

I need some help understanding what's going on here. It's a block inside of a method. Basically I get everything here except the call in the `if` statement `wasABlock_nowAProc.call`. This is not defined here, so what is it calling?

```
class Array

  def eachEven(&wasABlock_nowAProc)
    isEven = true  #  We start with "true" because arrays start with 0, which is even.

    self.each do |object|
      if isEven
        wasABlock_nowAProc.call object
      end

      isEven = (not isEven)  #  Toggle from even to odd, or odd to even.
    end
  end

end

['apple', 'bad apple', 'cherry', 'durian'].eachEven do |fruit|
  puts 'Yum!  I just love '+fruit+' pies, don\'t you?'
end

#  Remember, we are getting the even-numbered elements
#  of the array, all of which happen to be odd numbers,
#  just because I like to cause problems like that.
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5].eachEven do |oddBall|
  puts oddBall.to_s+' is NOT an even number!'
end
```

Comment: Apart from being some of the worst monkey-patching I've ever seen, [`.call`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Proc.html#method-i-call) is calling the proc.

Answer (score 1):

`def eachEven(&wasABlock_nowAProc)` declares that the eachEven method accepts a block, which is the `do ... end` stuff from your two examples. It is then accessible within the method as a `.call`able Proc/Lambda object with the name `wasABlock_nowAProc`.

`wasABlock_nowAProc.call object` basically invokes the attached block from within the method and passes it one argument, `object`.

Answer (score 0):

Do a google search for "ruby block to proc" and [any](http://www.reactive.io/tips/2008/12/21/understanding-ruby-blocks-procs-and-lambdas/) of the first results should give you a thorough explanation.

Basically, when you define a method parameter with an & prefix (as in `def eachEven(&wasABlock_nowAProc)`), it tells Ruby that this method is expecting to receive a [Proc object](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Proc.html) as an argument. In the method body you can then do stuff with Proc, such as use the `#call` method to run it or pass it on to another method.

Now, it's rare for Ruby programmer to manually create Proc objects. It's much more common to just use a block (less typing, easier to read, etc). If you try to pass a block to method that requires a Proc, well, Ruby handles that just fine. It magically converts the block to a Proc and uses that.

In this particular example, the only reason I can see to define the `&wasABlock_nowAProc` parameter is to tell Ruby to raise an error if the method is called with a block. You could remove the parameter and replace the `#call` line with `yield` to achieve the same functionality.